# No detail on error page even if published with Debug configuration

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-10

I have an MVC Core application, working perfectly running in debugging mode inside VS and IIS Express. Yet when I publish, under `Release` config, to IIS 10, an error occurs when I click the `Login` link. The site displays the utterly useless default error page, the one that comes as part of the VS project template for MVC applications. The only useful information in this page is that there has been an error, and that:

> Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed
>   information about the error that occurred.

So I took care to clean out the publish folder, where the website in IIS is pointed to, and published the app again, this time under `Debug` config.

Yet I still get exactly the same useless error page. Is this a problem with IIS, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Debug/Release` configuration by default has nothing with `Development/Production` environment. Check this [Environments section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1#environments) and [Hosting settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#environment) to find how to set needed environment. The easiest way is by specifying the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` env variable.

Regarding ***Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.***

This is about [`WebHostDefaults.DetailedErrorsKey` settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#detailed-errors):

> When enabled (or when the Environment is set to Development), the app captures detailed exceptions.

You can explicitly enable it via:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.DetailedErrorsKey, "true")
```

---

There is a [good doc sectio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.1)n about troubleshooting app deployed on IIS. Among other consider to enable [ASP.NET Core Module stdout logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.1#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log) in web.config:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"
            arguments=".\MyApp.dll"
            stdoutLogEnabled="true"
            stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
```

---

Also for detailed exceptions view you may enable the [Developer exception page](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-developer-exception-page). Keep in mind that the good practice (for security reason) is to setup this page for `Development` env only:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
```

---

And the last one in general (butt seems like not your case), you may also catch the startup errors by [captureStartupErrors setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#capture-startup-errors):

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
```

Comment: The first part of your answer shows how I was stupid is assuming that when the build config was set to `Release`, VS would automatically set the value of `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Production`. I don't know what got me stupid enough to just make that assumption.